# XlListObjectHasHeaders causing Run-time error '448': Named argument not found excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run the following code but keep getting a runtime error despite the code matching the MSDN page. When I remove the XlListObjectHasHeaders argument, the code runs just fine.

```
Dim c1 As Range
Set c1 = ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1).ResultRange
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=c1, TableStyleName:="TableStyleLight1", XlListObjectHasHeaders:=1).Name = "Test"
```

Answer (score 1):

I guessing your version of Excel is an earlier version than what was used in the MSDN example and doesn't use that parameter.